# JavaScript promise in recursive function

Tags: javascript, ajax, recursion, es6-promise

I have a function in my application that must execute multiple times for pagination, however after the first time, resolve never executes again. 
Am I missing something?

```
function start(){
    $.when(myrequest()).done(function(result){
         console.log(result);
    })
}

function myrequest(myurl){
    //NOTE this is just an example but the idea is the same. 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         $.ajax({
              url: myurl,
              method: "GET",
              contentType: "application/json",
              headers:{
                   Authorization: key
              },
              success: function(response) {
                 if (response.currenturl !== response.lasturl) {
                      myurl = response.nexturl;
                      //Do stuff with data here as well to create a list. 
                      myrequest(myurl);
                      //RESOLVES JUST FINE
                      resolve("test");
                 }else{
                      //DOESN'T RESOLVE
                      resolve("test");
                 }
              },
              error: function(response){
                   reject("error");
              }
         })
    })
}
```

Comment: You're not actually propagating the `Promise` that `myrequest` would return when you nest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like zero said you gotta propagate the recursive promise by returning that in the resolve.

```
success: function(response) {
             if (response.currenturl !== response.lasturl) {
                  myurl = response.nexturl;
                  //Do stuff with data here as well to create a list. 

                  // *heres magic
                  resolve(myrequest(myurl));
```

Comment: You are my hero dude. I have been beating my head against the wall for the last hour. Thank you man. As soon as I can accept I will

Answer (score 2):

your `myrequest(...);` call returns a promise, and on the monitor of that promise object you are performing further, so whenever that promise is resolved, that returned object's (then/done) handler will invoke, but in your recursive call of `myrequest(myurl);` , what that returns (A `promise`) you are not using that, and you are loosing that promise (kind of leak), so obviously, even if that promise is resolved, no one have a reference to that, so they can perform something for listening to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the recursive result (the promise) of `myrequest`.

For instance, you can do this:

```
if (response.currenturl !== response.lasturl) {
  myurl = response.nexturl;
  //Do stuff with data here as well to create a list. 
  $.when(myrequest(myurl)).done(function (result) {
    //RESOLVES JUST FINE
    resolve("test");
  });
}
```

Comment: My bigger issue is that I need it to return in the else clause. My list isn't completed until the else statement.

Comment: @basic I don't understand your comment. Did you try this snippet and is not working?

Comment: Issue resolved in another posters answer. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to create a new promise with `new Promise`, since `$.ajax` returns a promise already. Also, you don't need `$.when` which is mostly for dealing with an array of promises, but you only pass one promise to it. Instead, use the `then` method of the promise.

Something like this:

```
function start(startUrl){
    return myrequest(startUrl).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
}

function myrequest(myurl, collected = []){
    return $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers:{
           Authorization: key
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        if (response.currenturl !== response.lasturl) {
            // add something to the partial results, 
            // e.g. the url, but could be response data:
            collected.push(myurl);
            //Do stuff with data here as well to create a list.
            //...
            // Also pass on the partial results:
            return myrequest(response.nexturl, collected); 
        } else {
            return collected; // return all the results
        }
    });
}
```